# FreeRadius with DHCP config?

Tags: dhcp, freeradius

I need configuration of free radius with dhcp server module
I have installed free radius and dhcp module on ubuntu 18.04 but configuration file of dhcp is blank so I want know how i can run dhcp server with free radius ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently looking at the same thing, I did notice that from the docs currently only dhcp with SQL as the back end is supported, so the dhcp base config is essentially just a placeholder. If you look at the dhcp_sqlippool module you'll see it usable.

**Resources**

- https://wiki.freeradius.org/features/DHCP
- https://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/dhcp-for-static-ip-allocation